# Send Data from android app to php page

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

I am trying to successfully send data across from an android app to a php web app and display that data and save into a mysql database. However i don't get an exception or anything just the data i send across does not get received on the server end. My code is below:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        String text = "None";

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnOne:
                send();
                text = "Response Submitted";
                break;

            case R.id.btnTwo:
                text = "Two";
                break;

            case R.id.btnThree:
                text = "Three";
                break;

            case R.id.btnFour:
                text = "Four";
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void send() {
        URL a = null;
        try {
            a = new URL("http://cce.swlgroup.com/json.php/");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        new URLTestTask().execute(a);
    }

    private class URLTestTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {
       @Override
        protected void doInBackground(URL... urls) {

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://cce.swlgroup.com/json.php/");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                Log.e("", "" + conn.getResponseMessage());
                conn.connect();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("Marge","Simpson");

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
                post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(obj.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
                post.setHeader("json",obj.toString());

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                final String responseBody = client.execute(post,
                        responseHandler);
                HttpEntity ent = post.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = ent.getContent();
                String result = RestClient.convertStreamToString(stream);
                BufferedReader red = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ent.getContent()));
                String line;
                StringBuilder lb = new StringBuilder();
                while((line = red.readLine()) != null){
                    lb.append(red);
                }
                red.close();
                Log.i("Read from server", result);

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {

                if (conn != null)
                    conn.disconnect();

                try{
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

my php code is below to get data and display:

```
   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $obj = json_decode($json);
   var_dump($obj);
   var_dump($_POST);
   var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: why your doInBackground() method is  not overrided??

Comment: not sure why the doInBackground() should be overrrided. onlick method is overrided

Comment: doInBackground() method must be overrided as it is from Asynctask class

Comment: ok thanks for your time ,is my logic for sending data across correct?

Comment: that seems correct to me. To generate over rided method right click on UrlTestTask and select generate and then from that menu select override methods and from that select doInBackground method

Comment: and then cut and paste your logic from your method to this one

Comment: i have made the change and yet nothing seems to work on the server end

Comment: can you update that in your question

Comment: i have updated the question, is there any chance you can try this code on your local machine?

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: is your web service get or post?

Comment: sorry my mistake its a get request

Comment: then that's your mistake

Comment: web page is GET type

Comment: what change is required?

Comment: What I think is you apparently mixing 2 types of code. I would suggest to follow this link to use GET method with request header http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779700/how-to-addheader-in-httpget-method-in-android-app

Comment: You have to modify it according to yours

Comment: I made the change and posted code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/json.php/");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            Log.e("", "" + conn.getResponseMessage());
            conn.connect();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Marge","Simpson");

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            StringBuilder pat = new StringBuilder();
            HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
            post.setEntity(new     ByteArrayEntity(obj.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
            post.setHeader("json", obj.toString());
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("accept-encoding","gzip, deflate");
            post.setHeader("accept-language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
            post.setHeader("FormData",obj.toString());

            HttpResponse lazy = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity ent = lazy.getEntity();
            String lb = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
            pat.append(lb);
            Log.i("Read from server", pat.toString());

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();

            try{
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
```

I made the change in accordance with that code but it doesnt seem to send a result across.